# Multiple users on Android 7.0, need to extend privileges of the first one

Tags: multi-user

I have an Android 7.0 phone with two users (OnePlus 3, Oxygen OS 4.0.3). The first user (as it was created first in order of time) seems to have more privileges than the second one. For example, the phone boots on the first user, he can tweak certain configurations that the second cannot, and some apps (WiFi monitoring for example) don't work on the second user and more.

I'd like to extend the privileges to the second user, or at least to switch the main one so that the second will become fully operational on the phone.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way to do that, would be by deleting the first user account and then creating a new user account.

Comment: I was afraid of that, this means I'll lose all the files and apps and configs from the first user?